# MySql nested Store Procedure Call

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I have 2 stored Procedures in MySQL. I want to call one from the other but I need some help with the syntax

Here is Procedure 1 FindPreviousDate

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE `FindPreviousDate`(IN eventdate DATETIME, IN lookbackDays INT, IN symbol VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM Price a
WHERE a.eventDate between (eventDate - interval lookbackDays day) and (eventdate - interval 1 day) and a.symbol = symbol
ORDER BY a.eventDate DESC
LIMIT 1;
END
```

Here is Procedure 2 FindCloseEvent

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `FindCloseEvent`(IN startdate DATETIME, IN enddate DATETIME,IN symbol VARCHAR(20), IN cutoff DOUBLE)
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM Price a
WHERE a.eventDate between startdate and enddate and
(SELECT COUNT(*) from Price b where b.eventDate = a.eventDate and b.closePrice < cutoff and a.symbol = b.symbol and
(SELECT COUNT(*) from Price c where c.eventDate = (b.eventDate - interval 1 day) and c.closePrice >= cutoff and b.symbol = c.symbol));
END
```

I want to replace this code in Procedure 2 with the result of Procedure 1

```
(b.eventDate - interval 1 day)
```

I need help getting the syntax right. I'm not even sure if mySql allows for what I'm asking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On procedures you can use OUT variables, which get filled and are available outside the procedure. 
OR
Since a MySQL procedure does not return a value. You'll need a stored **function** to achieve this.

use the example given into below link to call a function1 from your procedure2
http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Procedure-Function/Callanotherfunction.htm

you can even store the result of function1 into some variable of procedure2 and use it later in query